Scratch - Generator random numbers and allocating them in a if/else conditional statement
I am trying to have it autogenerate a number, if that number is a 1 then it throws a strike, if that number is a 2 then it throws a ball.
Currently it gets stuck on either a 1 or 2 and just throws a ball/strike. How can I get this to work?
enter image description here
I tried to auto generate a number which works without the if/else conditional in there. Once I add if/else statement and then it only generates a constant number.

I used:

if pick random 1 to 2 = 1

action


else

action



and it worked. It was totally random (tested with rotation in an infinate loop), executed without any issues.
screenshot of code
